# What is the point of making a reference type nullable?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types) for nullable reference types says:

> The compiler uses those annotations to help you find potential null reference errors in your code. There's no runtime difference between a non-nullable reference type and a nullable reference type. The compiler doesn't add any runtime checking for non-nullable reference types. The benefits are in the compile-time analysis. The compiler generates warnings that help you find and fix potential null errors in your code. You declare your intent, and the compiler warns you when your code violates that intent.

What are the potential null errors? What intent do I declare using a nullable reference type? This is not clear to me.

Comment: `System.NullReferenceException`

Comment: I can't understand your confusion. I mean, if you are using (e.g.) a variable which wasn't assigned a value yet, there is a need to "throw" an error. What language are you used to? Maybe we can guide you to a logical correct thought process which makes sense.

Comment: You explicitly state that `null` is a proper and expected value for the reference and that your code will check for null to avoid an NullReferenceException.  If you forget to do that check then the compiler can generate an error, pointing out the oversight.

Comment: Null references are a big deal when you observe the bigger picture, i.e., the most frequent reasons why code fails at run-time. As the documentation states, you now have **compile-time analysis** that helps you spot this type of weakness in your code (i.e., you have code Analyzers that evaluate the possibility of dereferencing nulls when your code is not actually handling this scenario). In other words, you specify that *this reference could be null at some point* and Analyzers can tell you *all right, but you're not actually handling this here and here* or *in this scenario, it could be null*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some sample code helps you to understand better:

```
string? myString1 = RemoveDots1("Hel.lo");
string myString2 = RemoveDots1("Hel.lo"); // warning: the function might return null, but you declared myString2 as non nullable.


myString1 = null;
myString2 = null; // warning: you should not do that, because you declared myString2 as non nullable.

myString1 = RemoveDots1(myString1);
myString1 = RemoveDots2(myString1); // warning: myString1 could be null, but its expecting a non nullable string


string? RemoveDots1(string? myString)
{
    return myString.Replace(".", ""); // warning: myString could be null
}


string RemoveDots2(string myString)
{
    return myString.Replace(".", "");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Originally, all reference-type variables were nullable. This meant that you always had to consider the possibility of a null reference and code accordingly. If it was your intention that a variable never be null, there was no way to enforce that. If you treated it like it would never be null, there was always the possibility of a NullReferenceException at run time if someone mistakenly set it to null.

Now, you can specify which variables should be nullable and which shouldn't and the compiler will enforce that. If you try to make a non-nullable variable null, a compiler error will prevent that. If you treat a nullable variable as though it definitely won't be null, a compiler warning will alert you.

Comment: Technically you still DO have to check method parameters for null - even if they are declared as non-nullable - because someone can still call the method and pass a null parameter using the null-forgiving operator, e.g. `FuncWithNonNullParam(null!);` (Well, you don't HAVE to check, but if you don't then at some point you could get a `NullReferenceException` rather than an `ArgumentNullException`, for example.

Comment: "If you try to make a non-nullable variable null, a compiler error will prevent that. " This is not correct.